# SQL Developer 4.0.0 sqlcli command on OS X throwing StringIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: macos, oracle-sqldeveloper

Running SQL Developer on Darwin Kernel Version 12.4.0 when I run any `sqlcli` command I get the following error:

```
box:sqldeveloper user$ ./sqlcli format input=sqlFile.sql output=outSqlFile.sql
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1
at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1911)
at oracle.dbtools.raptor.scriptrunner.utils.SqlCli.processArgs(SqlCli.java:43)
at oracle.dbtools.raptor.scriptrunner.utils.SqlCli.main(SqlCli.java:118)
```

Any thoughts on where to start troubleshooting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [release notes](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/downloads/sqldev-releasenotes-v4-1925251.html#support) for this [early adopter release](http://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2013/07/oracle-sql-developer-4-0-is-finally-here/) say:

> All SQL Developer 4.0 Early Adopter issues can be reported on the
>   [Oracle SQL Developer](http://forums.oracle.com/forums/forum.jspa?forumID=260) forum. Mark the subject with **4.0EA1**.

Having said that, it looks like it's expecting a connection string as the first parameter, and I'd guess the index error is coming from it looking for an `@` symbol (but it is only a guess, based on trying a few values). With a dummy value I get a different error:

```
bash ./sqlcli a/b@c
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: oracle/ide/Version
    at oracle.dbtools.db.DBUtil.<clinit>(DBUtil.java:1703)
    at oracle.dbtools.raptor.scriptrunner.utils.SqlCli.processArgs(SqlCli.java:49)
    at oracle.dbtools.raptor.scriptrunner.utils.SqlCli.main(SqlCli.java:118)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.ide.Version
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 3 more
```

I have the instant client installed and DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH set <strike>so I'm not sure what that's about</strike>. This is because the `CP` setting in `sqlcli` is wrong; the `javatools` version should be 12.1.2:

```
#CP=${CP}:modules/oracle.javatools_11.1.1/javatools-nodeps.jar
CP=${CP}:modules/oracle.javatools_12.1.2/javatools-nodeps.jar
```

With that change I start getting sensible errors about the connection, and using a valid connect string it then tells me:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: format.sql (No such file or directory)
...
```

So it's trying to run a script called `format`, not format your existing files. I think you're using the wrong tool.

The command line client [has been rewritten](http://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2013/07/sql-developer-4-0-and-the-command-line-interface-cli/), and `sdcli` seems to work. I've just downloaded and expanded the beta, and installed JDK 7u25, so this might not quite match what you need to do:

```
cd SQLDeveloper.app/Contents/Resources/sqldeveloper/sqldeveloper/bin
bash ./sdcli format input=/tmp/in.sql output=/tmp/out.sql
```

I needed to set the JDK path to `/usr` the first time:

```
Type the full pathname of a J2SE installation (or Ctrl-C to quit), the path will be stored in ~/.sqldeveloper/jdk
/usr
```

... but not on subsequent runs.

```
 Oracle SQL Developer
 Copyright (c) 1997, 2013, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Sep 10, 2013 10:04:27 AM javax.ide.extension.spi.DefaultElementContext resolveResource
SEVERE: jar:/file:/Users/alex/Downloads/SQLDeveloper.app/Contents/Resources/sqldeveloper/sqldeveloper/extensions/oracle.sqldeveloper.migration.application.jar!/META-INF/extension.xml:16: Resource not found: '${SCRATCH_COMMAND_ICON}'.
Success!
```

The `SCRATCH_COMMAND_ICON` error is a known 'harmless but annoying' issue that you can apparently ignore.

Comment: Thank you Alex!  I had seen Jeff's post and have had success with `sdcli` using a `JAVA_HOME` of `/usr` _or_ `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_25.jdk/Contents/Home`, I was just unclear that the `sqlcli` had been abandoned.  I'll log the issue on the Oracle forum.

Comment: @eebbesen - I haven't ever used the `sqlcli` tool; did it use to support the `format` command, and the others listed as 'available commands' in Jeff's post? At the moment it seems like an SQL*Plus replacement, which I suppose is the point, but I don't know if it used to do more than it seems to now.

Comment: I think you're right, @AlexPoole -- I was confused about `sqlcli` vs. `sdcli` while searching around for `format.sh`, which used to be a standalone script in SQL Developer.  Now that I think about the name, it should have been obvious to me that the former would be an Oracle client.

Comment: @eebbesen - yes, looking at `format.sh` from 3.2.20, that ran a separate `headless` executable, so that seems to have been separate from `sqlcli`. I guess they've moved that functionality into `sdcli` now, and maybe haven't done much to `sqlcli`. That isn't how I'd read that post either.

Comment: @eebbesen - I've raised the `sqlcli` issue on the [SQL Developer forum](https://forums.oracle.com/thread/2582391) too, as it's still present in 4.0EA2.